# SQL Text line break at random points

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a nvarchar(max) field that has a text that should display as screen1.  [image: screen1]

But when I select the text and put that on a email body I get it like screen2.  How can I format the string in select query to solve this?

[image: screen2]

When entering the data to the sql field in the table we have added a new line character after every line.

Comment: Hi Thank You for the quick support It is SQL Server 2012

Comment: Is the E-mail format plain text or HTML? (Note: HTML completely ignores line brakes).

Comment: It is plain text

Comment: Your question isn't clear, but your probably want `char(13)` or `char(10)`. Why wouldn't you insert these in separate rows?

Comment: Hi scsimon, I can explain further if you point the unclear point.  Yes I think i have to use char(13) or char(10). And probably the 'Replace' function.  The question is 'replace what from what?' As In the original text it already have a line break.  This text is keep to describe an Item which is a unique key. The text generated from reading an xml file which get generate from a separate software

Comment: Are you trying to copy this data from a cell and paste it in email body?

Comment: Look at the hex and see what your really have.  I bet you have some cases of cr of lf but not both.

Comment: I am generating the email from a Stored Procedure selecting this text from a table. I can't generate a html email because of some restrictions in the system i use.

Comment: Hi Paparazzi, I didn't follow you.  Could you please explain how to check the hex.

Comment: It also only appears to be a problem when you come across a PDF entry. perhaps that branch in the code is different than the other branches that writes out the data?

Comment: Hi, Yes that could be it.  But how can I identify the difference.  When I put that in to word and do paragraph mark it look same.

Comment: Can someone guide me how to check hex as Paparazzi suggested above.